# Select option typing part of the text

Tags: html, tags

I know that when a SELECT is focused and you type any letter, you are automatically redirected to the first most similar option. Is there a way to add some sort of "tags" so that I can reach an option by typing part of the text?

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Red fish</option>
  <option value="2">Black snake</option>
  <option value="3">Green frog</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is to reach "Black snake" only by typing "snake" and not "Black ...". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a simple HTML `select`.

The most common method to accomplish this is to use an autosuggestion or autocompleting feature on a search field.